# Insertar url en codigo php?

Tags: php, url

Hola he buscado en todos lados y no he podido encontrar una solucion a mi problema y tal vez alguien me ayude jeje, tengo una pagina web en la cual yo quiero activar a mis usuarios desde la pagina de administracion, pues resulta que el codigo php es este:

```
 <table cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" id="member">

        <thead>

            <tr>

                <th colspan="10">Players Not Activated</th>

            </tr>

            <tr>

                <td class="on">#</td>

                <td class="on">ID</td>

                <td class="on">Username</td>

                <td class="on">Email</td>

                <td class="on">Tribe</td>

                <td class="on">Activation Code</td>

                <td class="on">Act 2??</td>

                <td class="on">Time</td>

                <td class="on">PLAY</td>

            </tr>

        </thead>

        <tbody>

            <?php

                $sql = "SELECT * FROM ".TB_PREFIX."activate";

                $result = mysqli_query($GLOBALS["link"], $sql);

                while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))

                {

                    $i++;

                    if($row['tribe'] == 1) {$tribe = "Roman"; }

                    elseif($row['tribe'] == 2) {$tribe = "Teuton"; }

                    elseif($row['tribe'] == 3) {$tribe = "Gaul"; }

                    echo "

                    <tr>

                        <td>".$i."</td>

                        <td>".$row['id']."</td>

                        <td>".$row['username']."</td>

                        <td><a href=\"mailto:".$row['email']."\">".$row['email']."</a></td>

                        <td>".$tribe."</td>

                        <td>".$row['act']."</td>

                        <td>".$row['act2']."</td>

                        <td class=\"hab\">".date('d:m:Y H:i', $row['timestamp'])."</td>

                        <td><a href=\"http://www.travianforce.com.es/s8/activate.php?code=".$act.">Yes!</a></td>

                    </tr>";

                }

            ?>

        </tbody>

    </table>
```

y la url que quiero introducir es esta:

```
<td><a href=\"http://www.travianforce.com.es/s8/activate.php?code=".$act.">Yes!</a></td>
```

En Account.php este es el codigo php:

```
<?php

use App\Entity\User;



#################################################################################

##              -= YOU MAY NOT REMOVE OR CHANGE THIS NOTICE =-                 ##

## --------------------------------------------------------------------------- ##

##  Project:       TravianZ                                                    ##

##  Version:       22.06.2015                                      ##

##  Filename       Account.php                                                 ##

##  Developed by:  Mr.php , Advocaite , brainiacX , yi12345 , Shadow , ronix   ##

##  Fixed by:      Shadow - STARVATION , HERO FIXED COMPL.                 ##

##  Fixed by:      InCube - double troops                      ##

##  License:       TravianZ Project                                            ##

##  Copyright:     TravianZ (c) 2010-2015. All rights reserved.                ##

##  URLs:          http://travian.shadowss.ro                              ##

##  Source code:   https://github.com/Shadowss/TravianZ                    ##

##                                                                             ##

#################################################################################



global $autoprefix;



// go max 5 levels up - we don't have folders that go deeper than that

$autoprefix = '';

for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {

    $autoprefix = str_repeat('../', $i);

    if (file_exists($autoprefix.'autoloader.php')) {

        // we have our path, let's leave

        break;

    }

}



include_once($autoprefix."GameEngine/Session.php");



class Account {



    function __construct() {

        global $session;

        if(isset($_POST['ft'])) {

            switch($_POST['ft']) {

                case "a1":

                $this->Signup();

                break;

                case "a2":

                $this->Activate();

                break;

                case "a3":

                $this->Unreg();

                break;

                case "a4":

                $this->Login();

                break;

            }

        } if(isset($_GET['code'])) {

        $_POST['id'] = $_GET['code']; $this->Activate();

        }

        else {

            if($session->logged_in && in_array("logout.php",explode("/",$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']))) {

                $this->Logout();

            }

        }

    }



    private function Signup() {

        global $database,$form,$mailer,$generator,$session;

        if(!isset($_POST['name']) || trim($_POST['name']) == "") {

            $form->addError("name",USRNM_EMPTY);

        }

        else {

            if(strlen($_POST['name']) < USRNM_MIN_LENGTH) {

                $form->addError("name",USRNM_SHORT);

            }

            else if(!USRNM_SPECIAL && preg_match('/[^0-9A-Za-z]/',$_POST['name'])) {

                $form->addError("name",USRNM_CHAR);

            }

            else if(USRNM_SPECIAL && preg_match("/[:,\\. \\n\\r\\t\\s\\<\\>]+/", $_POST['name'])) {

                $form->addError("name",USRNM_CHAR);

            }

            else if(strtolower($_POST['name']) == 'natars') {

                $form->addError("name",USRNM_TAKEN);

            }

            else if(User::exists($database,$_POST['name'])) {

                $form->addError("name",USRNM_TAKEN);

            }



        }

        if(!isset($_POST['pw']) || trim($_POST['pw']) == "") {

            $form->addError("pw",PW_EMPTY);

        }

        else {

            if(strlen($_POST['pw']) < PW_MIN_LENGTH) {

                $form->addError("pw",PW_SHORT);

            }

            else if($_POST['pw'] == $_POST['name']) {

                $form->addError("pw",PW_INSECURE);



            }

        }

        if(!isset($_POST['email'])) {

            $form->addError("email",EMAIL_EMPTY);

        }

        else {

            if(!$this->validEmail($_POST['email'])) {

                $form->addError("email",EMAIL_INVALID);

            }

            else if(User::exists($database,$_POST['email'])) {

                $form->addError("email",EMAIL_TAKEN);

            }

        }

        if(!isset($_POST['vid']) || !in_array($_POST['vid'], [1, 2, 3])) {

            $form->addError("tribe",TRIBE_EMPTY);

        }

        if(!isset($_POST['agb'])) {

            $form->addError("agree",AGREE_ERROR);

        }

        if($form->returnErrors() > 0) {

            $form->addError("invt",$_POST['invited']);

            $_SESSION['errorarray'] = $form->getErrors();

            $_SESSION['valuearray'] = $_POST;





            header("Location: anmelden.php");

            exit;

        }

        else {

            if(AUTH_EMAIL){

            $act = $generator->generateRandStr(10);

            $act2 = $generator->generateRandStr(5);

            $uid = $database->activate($_POST['name'],password_hash($_POST['pw'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT,['cost' => 12]),$_POST['email'],$_POST['vid'],$_POST['kid'],$act,$act2);

                if($uid) {



                    $mailer->sendActivate($_POST['email'],$_POST['name'],$_POST['pw'],$act);

                    header("Location: activate.php?id=$uid&q=$act2");

                    exit;

                }

            }

            else {

                $uid = $database->register($_POST['name'],password_hash($_POST['pw'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT,['cost' => 12]),$_POST['email'],$_POST['vid'],$act);

                if($uid) {

                    setcookie("COOKUSR",$_POST['name'],time()+COOKIE_EXPIRE,COOKIE_PATH);

                    setcookie("COOKEMAIL",$_POST['email'],time()+COOKIE_EXPIRE,COOKIE_PATH);

                    $database->updateUserField(

                        $uid,

                        ["act", "invited"],

                        ["", $_POST['invited']],

                        1

                    );



                    $this->generateBase($_POST['kid'],$uid,$_POST['name']);

                    header("Location: login.php");

                    exit;

                }

            }

        }

    }



    private function Activate() {

        if(START_DATE < date('m/d/Y') or START_DATE == date('m/d/Y') && START_TIME <= date('H:i'))

       {

            global $database;

            $q = "SELECT act, username, password, email, tribe, location FROM ".TB_PREFIX."activate where act = '".$database->escape($_POST['id'])."'";

            $result = mysqli_query($GLOBALS['link'],$q);

            $dbarray = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

            if($dbarray['act'] == $_POST['id']) {

                $uid = $database->register($dbarray['username'],$dbarray['password'],$dbarray['email'],$dbarray['tribe'],"");

                if($uid) {

                $database->unreg($dbarray['username']);

                $this->generateBase($dbarray['location'],$uid,$dbarray['username']);

                header("Location: activate.php?e=2");

                exit;

                }

            }

            else

            {

                header("Location: activate.php?e=3");

                exit;

            }

       }

       else

       {

            header("Location: activate.php");

            exit;

       }



    }



    private function Unreg() {

        global $database;

        $q = "SELECT password, username FROM ".TB_PREFIX."activate where id = ".(int) $_POST['id'];

        $result = mysqli_query($GLOBALS['link'],$q);

        $dbarray = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

        if(password_verify($_POST['pw'], $dbarray['password'])) {

            $database->unreg($dbarray['username']);

            header("Location: anmelden.php");

            exit;

        }

        else {

            header("Location: activate.php?e=3");

            exit;

        }

    }



    private function Login() {

        global $database,$session,$form;

        $user = $_POST['user'];

        if(!isset($_POST['user']) || $_POST['user'] == "") {

            $form->addError("user",$user);

        }

        else if(!User::exists($database,$_POST['user'])) {

            $form->addError("user",USR_NT_FOUND);

        }

        if(!isset($_POST['pw']) || $_POST['pw'] == "") {

            $form->addError("pw",LOGIN_PASS_EMPTY);

        }

        else if(!$database->login($_POST['user'],$_POST['pw']) && !$database->sitterLogin($_POST['user'],$_POST['pw'])) {

            // try activation data if the user was not found

            if (!$userData) {

                $activateData = $database->getActivateField( $_POST['user'], 'act', 1 );



                if ( $activateData != "" ) {

                    $form->addError( "activate", $_POST['user'] );

                } else {

                    $form->addError("pw",LOGIN_PW_ERROR);

                }

            } else {

                $form->addError("pw",LOGIN_PW_ERROR);

            }

        }



        $userData = $database->getUserArray($_POST['user'], 0);



        // Vacation mode by Shadow

        if($userData["vac_mode"] == 1 && $userData["vac_time"] > time()) {

            $form->addError("vacation","Vacation mode is still enabled");

        }



        // Vacation mode by Shadow

        if($form->returnErrors() > 0) {

            $_SESSION['errorarray'] = $form->getErrors();

            $_SESSION['valuearray'] = $_POST;



            header("Location: login.php");

            exit;

        } else {

            // Vacation mode by Shadow

            $database->removevacationmode($userData['id']);

            // Vacation mode by Shadow

            if($database->login($_POST['user'],$_POST['pw'])){

                $database->UpdateOnline("login" ,$_POST['user'],time(),$userData['id']);

            }else if($database->sitterLogin($_POST['user'],$_POST['pw'])){

                $database->UpdateOnline("sitter" ,$_POST['user'],time(),$userData['id']);

            }

                setcookie("COOKUSR",$_POST['user'],time()+COOKIE_EXPIRE,COOKIE_PATH);

                $session->login($_POST['user']);

        }

    }



    private function Logout() {

        global $session,$database;

        unset($_SESSION['wid']);

        $database->activeModify(addslashes($session->username),1);

        $database->UpdateOnline("logout") or die(mysqli_error($database->dblink));

        $session->Logout();

    }



    private function validEmail($email) {

      $regexp="/^[a-z0-9]+([_\\.-][a-z0-9]+)*@([a-z0-9]+([\.-][a-z0-9]+)*)+\\.[a-z]{2,}$/i";

      if ( !preg_match($regexp, $email) ) {

           return false;

      }

      return true;

    }



    function generateBase($kid,$uid,$username) {

        global $database,$message;

        if($kid == 0) {

            $kid = rand(1,4);

        }

        else{

            $kid = $_POST['kid'];

        }



        $wid = $database->generateBase($kid,0);

        $database->setFieldTaken($wid);

        $database->addVillage($wid,$uid,$username,1);

        $database->addResourceFields($wid,$database->getVillageType($wid));

        $database->addUnits($wid);

        $database->addTech($wid);

        $database->addABTech($wid);

        $database->updateUserField($uid,"access",USER,1);



        $message = new Message();

        $message->sendWelcome($uid,$username);

    }



};

$account = new Account;

?>
```

Este es el codigo que he modificado agregando y declarando la variable $act, péro aun asi me da error! =(

```
<table cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" id="member">

        <thead>

            <tr>

                <th colspan="10">Players Not Activated</th>

            </tr>

            <tr>

                <td class="on">#</td>

                <td class="on">ID</td>

                <td class="on">Username</td>

                <td class="on">Email</td>

                <td class="on">Tribe</td>

                <td class="on">Activation Code</td>

                <td class="on">Act 2??</td>

                <td class="on">Time</td>

                            <td class="on">Play!</td>

            </tr>

        </thead>

        <tbody>

            <?php

                $sql = "SELECT * FROM ".TB_PREFIX."activate";

                $result = mysqli_query($GLOBALS["link"], $sql);

                while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))

                {

                    $i++;

                    if($row['tribe'] == 1) {$tribe = "Roman"; }

                    elseif($row['tribe'] == 2) {$tribe = "Teuton"; }

                    elseif($row['tribe'] == 3) {$tribe = "Gaul"; }

                    elseif($act = $_GET['code'];

                    echo "

                    <tr>

                        <td>".$i."</td>

                        <td>".$row['id']."</td>

                        <td>".$row['username']."</td>

                        <td><a href=\"mailto:".$row['email']."\">".$row['email']."</a></td>

                        <td>".$tribe."</td>

                        <td>".$row['act']."</td>

                        <td>".$row['act2']."</td>

                        <td class=\"hab\">".date('d:m:Y H:i', $row['timestamp'])."</td>

    <td><a href=\"http://www.travianforce.com.es/s8/activate.php?code=".$act.">Yes!</a></td>

                    </tr>";

                }

            ?>

        </tbody>

    </table>
```

pero cuando lo pongo me muestra una pagina en blanco, no se que estoy haciendo mal o talvez es que necesite habilitar alguna funcion o algo asi, no se pero ya me duele la cabeza jeje, por favor si alguien sabe como hacer funcionar este link le estaria muy agradecido, este url que se supone que diga "Yes!" va en la seccion de "PLAY" en la tabla, osea que cuando yo le de click en este enlace automaticamente activare al usuario,ya he probado el link con el codigo armado en partes en el bloc de notas y al colocarlo en direccion de google y darle enter, si activa a los jugadores,muchas gracias y espero su ayuda! =) Feliz Noche!

Comment: La variable $act de donde la estas sacando? No veo declaración por ningún lado

Comment: Hola esa variable la tomo de Account.php desde el campo "act" que significa activation code de la tabla users en la base de datos! muchas gracias por ayudar =)

Comment: como puedo declarar esa variable Juan Carlos?

Comment: El codigo que muestras al es parte de Account.php o es un codigo aparte? Si es un codigo aparte debes hacer un include de Account.php en ese archivo donde estas armando la tabla.

Comment: Ahora, no entiendo bien cual es tu fin, pero si solo deseas activar a un usuario desde un panel de administración lo mas idoneo seria que tuviera un campo en la base que diga activo, cuando le den al link envie el id del usuario que deseas activar a un archivo PHP o lo que desees y allí haces UPDATE en la tabla usuario donde el Id sea igual al enviado.

Comment: Si la página que contiene el HTML tiene una extensión `.php`, puedes hacerlo así: `<a href="http://www.travianforce.com.es/s8/activate.php?code=<?php echo $act; ?>">`

Comment: Verifica bien el código, el hace un echo con todo el contenido de la fila

Comment: Hola he añadido el codigo completo de Account.php y tambien la funcion Activate con la cual se activa a los jugadores, pero tambien me interesa lo de  el link, yto tengo la tabla activate en mi base de datos pero no se como hacer para poder crear un link directo que se conecte con mi base de datos en mi panel de administracion para activar a los usuarios. no se que opinan ustedes!

Comment: Muchas gracias Juan Carlos pero no me funciona me sale en blanco la pagina y cuando quito el enlace vuelve todo a la normalidad, dejame decirte que en todo este tiempo no he visto que el link funcione, pero si funciona y sale como link la parte de <a href=\"mailto:".$row['email']."\">".$row['email']."</a>, no se que pasa con este codigo php me parece que no deja colocar links o algo parecido!

Comment: La verdad amigo el codgio como me lo muestras se me hace confuso, pero veo que recuperas $act de la base de datos. Por que no simplemente colocar en ves de $act a $row['act']. Seria algo asi.

`<a href=\"http://www.travianforce.com.es/s8/activate.php?code=". $row['act'].">`

Comment: Hola he probado el link pero me sale en blanco tambien, que podria ser que no me deja colocar links, no se pero pienso que puede deberse a que falta una autorizacion para poner url o algo asi , no se dime tu!

Comment: Hola Juan Carlos he colocado el link,no me muestra pagina en blanco pero no me aparece el indicador del url que seria "Yes" este es url que he puesto:`<td><a href=\"http://www.travianforce.com.es/s8/activate.php?code=". $row['act'].">Yes</a></td>

Comment: Hola alguien puede ayudarme? muchas gracias!

Comment: Hola gracias a Juan ya no me da el error 500 pero no me aparece el link, no porque no me aparece el link "Yes!", saludos