# No me aparece el link de la url php?

Tags: php

Hola tengo problemas para hacer funcionar un codigo de php que sirve para activar a mis usuarios desde mi panel de administracion, cuando ejecuto el codigo me funciona pero no me muestra el link de "ACTIVATE"

no se que estoy colocando mal y sinceramente no se que hacer! pero aqui esta el codigo, la variable $row['act'] la saco de la base de datos en el campo"act" de la tabla "s8_activate" de la base de datos! y este es el codigo de activeme.php donde tengo el problema!:

```
<table cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" id="member">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="10">Players Not Activated</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="on">#</td>
            <td class="on">ID</td>
            <td class="on">Username</td>
            <td class="on">Email</td>
            <td class="on">Tribe</td>
            <td class="on">Activation Code</td>
            <td class="on">Act 2??</td>
            <td class="on">Time</td>
            <td class="on">*PLAY*</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php


@include("GameEngine/config.php");
@include("GameEngine/Database.php");






            $sql = "SELECT * FROM ".s8_."activate";
            $result = mysqli_query($GLOBALS["link"], $sql);
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
            {
                $i++;
                if($row['tribe'] == 1) {$tribe = "Roman"; }
                elseif($row['tribe'] == 2) {$tribe = "Teuton"; }
                elseif($row['tribe'] == 3) {$tribe = "Gaul"; }
                                echo "
                <tr>
                    <td>".$i."</td>
                    <td>".$row['id']."</td>
                    <td>".$row['username']."</td>
                    <td><a href=\"mailto:".$row['email']."\">".$row['email']."</a></td>
                    <td>".$tribe."</td>
                    <td>".$row['act']."</td>
                    <td>".$row['act2']."</td>
                    <td class=\"hab\">".date('d:m:Y H:i', $row['timestamp'])."</td>
   <td><a href=\"http://www.travianforce.com.es/s8/activate.php?code=". $row['act'].">ACTIVATE</a></td>

                </tr>";
            }
        ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

No se porque motivo me aparece en espacio en blanco el link que se supone tiene que aparecer abajo de *PLAY* y tiene que decir "ACTIVATE" y que cuando le de click en el enlance pueda activar a mis usuarios de forma instantanea, si alguien me puede ayudar le estaria infinitamente agradecido! muchas gracias!

Aqui esta la imagen para que vean el error saludos! =)
https://ibb.co/vzr7D8T

Atte. Jose Oliva

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Insertar url en codigo php?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/345848/insertar-url-en-codigo-php)

Comment: no amigo no soluciona mi problema jeje !

Comment: Pero tampoco lo vas a solucionar duplicando preguntas, al contrario, vas a tardar más en obtener algo concreto.

Comment: Hola es que en la anterior pregunta era porque me daba error 500 pero ya lo solucione gracias a Juan, si tu crees que puedes ayudarme con este problema te estaria muy agradecido, saludos! =)

Comment: Hola ya he editado la pregunta saludos! =)

Answer (score 0):

te falta `</a>`

```
echo "
                <tr>
                    <td>".$i."</td>
                    <td>".$row['id']."</td>
                    <td>".$row['username']."</td>
                    <td><a href=\"mailto:".$row['email']."\">".$row['email']."</a></td>
                    <td>".$tribe."</td>
                    <td>".$row['act']."</td>
                    <td>".$row['act2']."</td>
                    <td class=\"hab\">".date('d:m:Y H:i', $row['timestamp'])."</td>
   <td><a href=\"http://www.travianforce.com.es/s8/activate.php?code=". $row['act'].">ACTIVATE</a></td>

                </tr>";
```

Comment: Hola aun asi ya lo he intentado y me da el mismo error que no me aparece el link, hay no se que hacer  jeje =)